# extract starting and ending with a special character

Tags: text-processing

I have a comma separated file which is not a standard csv file like this:

```
XYZ,143,ABC/genomes/date/pa341,dog,available
567,FTR/genomes/date/ha76870,horse,waiting
214,GEN/genomes/date/btr256,N/A,avialable,stored
...
```

I want to extract all the strings that start with "/genomes" until the next comma "," character. The expected output would be:

```
/genomes/date/pa341
/genomes/date/ha76870
/genomes/date/btr256
```

I have tried the following but it prints extra info that I do not need:

```
grep -o '/genomes.*,' myfile.txt 

output:
/genomes/date/pa341,dog,
/genomes/date/ha76870,horse,
/genomes/date/btr256,N/A,stored
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach fails because `*` means "match the longest possible string". This is known as a "greedy" modifier. You want "match the shortest possible string", a non-greedy operator. So, if your `grep` supports it, use `-P` to enable extended regular expressions and run:

```
$ grep -Po '/genomes.*?,' file 
/genomes/date/pa341,
/genomes/date/ha76870,
/genomes/date/btr256,
```

However, a better approach would be to match as many non-`,` characters as you can:

```
$ grep -o '/genomes[^,]*' file 
/genomes/date/pa341
/genomes/date/ha76870
/genomes/date/btr256
```

Comment: Solved my problem, thanks.

Comment: @NamAshena you're welcome. If one of the answers solved your issue, please take a moment to [accept it](//$$SITEURL/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of methods to get the information:

```
$ grep -oP '/genomes((?!,).)*'  myfile.txt

$ perl -F, -pale '
     shift @F until $F[0] =~ m{/genomes.*};
     $_ = $&;
'  myfile.txt

$ perl -lne '
     my $p1 = index $_, "/genomes";
     my $p2 = index $_, ",", $p1;
    print substr $_, $p1, $p2-$p1;
' myfile.txt

$ sed -ne '
     /\n/!s|/genomes|\n&|
    y/,/\n/
   /^\/genomes/!D;P
' myfile.txt
```

**Results:**

```
/genomes/date/pa341
/genomes/date/ha76870
/genomes/date/btr256
```